# marginal distribution of $X$ . given probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions

> The continuous random variables $X,Y$ have  joint probability density function $f(x,y)=e^{-2x^2-2y^2}$. Then what is the marginal distribution of $X$

What i try: Marginal distribution of $X$ is given by $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x,y)dy=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2x^2-2y^2}dy$$

$$=e^{-2x^2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2y^2}dy$$

Please tell me is my process is right.

If it is right Then how do i solve that definite Integration, thanks

Comment: Your argument is correct but your distribution is not normalized.

Comment: Can u please tell me How can i normalize it

Comment: $f$ is not normalized. To normalize it, divide by it's integral over the allowed values (here the plane $x,y$). The integral you encounter is called a Gaussian integral. It's one of the most famous result in the history of integration. I suggest you to Google it.

Comment: Is its answer is $$\displaystyle \frac{e^{-2x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$, where  $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2y^2}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Comment: @Ivc i did not understand that line. Divide it by integral over the allowed value.

Comment: You random variables $X,Y$ can presumably assume all values between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. These are the allowed values. It should be an input of the problem, although i this case it seems clear enough from context.